# Autowired spring dependency is always null in abstract base class when extending AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have an abstract test base class which extends from `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-test-config.xml" })
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = ActiveProfileResolver.class)
public abstract class BaseTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private MyActions myActions;

    @BeforeSuite(dependsOnMethods = "beforeSuite", alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeUISuite() {
        myActions.doSomething();
    }
}
```

And a test class which extends from `BaseTest`

```
public class ExampleTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void exampleTest( ){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

When the `beforeUISuite` method runs, `myActions` is always null. Why is this not autowired by Spring? Autowired dependencies in `ExampleTest` are correctly set when the test runs, but when `beforeUISuite` executes, nothing has been wired up?

If I make `myActions` protected and comment out `beforeUISuite`, `myActions` is correctly instantiated when the test runs. It seems like it isn't wired before the method marked `@BeforeSuite` executes?

Comment: Because Spring hasn't had a change to do the injection yet. `@BeforeSuite` runs before the spring callbacks are invoked and thus auto wired dependencies aren't available in `@BeforeSuite` annotated method. Much like the `@BeforeClass` in JUnit based tests.